# AJAX passing value confusion

Tags: javascript, php, ajaxform

I was looking for a way to submit data through a button so that the data will be saved or updated in database, without reloading. Now updating and inserting of data works. But I have used `dataString` a javaScript variable. I thought through this `dataString` variable post data are passed. But when I removed that variable from my code data insert or update was still working. So how the passing of data working here.

How post method gets the data from my ajax call here.

```
<html>
   <title>Registration</title>

<body>
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "nopass";
    $dbname = "registration_project";

  // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    ?>
    <div style="width:350px">
        <div style="float:left;width:40%">
            Id:<br/><br/>
            First Name:<br/><br/>
            Last Name:<br/><br/> 
            Age:<br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div style="float:left;width:60%">
            <form action="" method="post">
                <input type="number" id="id_id" name="id" value=<?php
                if (isset($_POST['id']))
                    echo $_POST['id'];
                ?>><br /><br />
                <input type="text" id="id_fname" name="fname" value=<?php
                if (isset($_POST['fname']))
                    echo $_POST['fname'];
                ?>><br /><br />
                <input type="text" id="id_lname" name="lname" value=<?php
                if (isset($_POST['lname']))
                    echo $_POST['lname'];
                ?>><br /><br />
                <input type="number" id="id_age" name="age" value=<?php
                if (isset($_POST['age']))
                    echo $_POST['age'];
                ?>><br /><br />
                <input type="submit" id="id_submit" name="submit">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['id']))
 echo $_POST['id'] . "<br/><br/>";
if (isset($_POST['fname']))
 echo $_POST['fname'] . "<br/><br/>";
if (isset($_POST['lname']))
 echo $_POST['lname'] . "<br/><br/>";
if (isset($_POST['age']))
 echo $_POST['age'] . "<br/><br/>";
?>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $fname = $_POST['fname'];
   $lname = $_POST['lname'];
   $age = $_POST['age'];
   $sql = "select max(id) from registration";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
     while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id = $row["max(id)"];
     }
   } else {
    echo "0 results";
   }

   if ($id==$_POST['id']) {
     $id = $_POST['id'];
     $sql = "update registration set firstName='$fname', lastName='$lname',             age=$age where id=$id";
     mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
} else {
    $id=$_POST['id'];
    $sql = "Insert into registration(id,firstName,lastName,age) values($id,'$fname','$lname',$age)";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
 }
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
<script>
    $("#id_submit").click(function(e) {
 var id = $("#id_id").val();
 var fname = $("#id_fname").val(); 
 var lname = $("#id_lname").val();
 var age = $("#id_age").val();
 var dataString = "id="+id+ '&fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&age='+age;
 //console.log(dataString);
 $.ajax({
 type:'POST',
 data:dataString,
 url:'Registration.php',
 success:function(data) {

    }
  });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: You have a syntax error, you have nothing after `data:`. That prevents the Javascript from running, so the form is being submitted in the normal way.

Comment: You also need to put `e.preventDefault()` in the function, to prevent normal form submission.

Comment: Ok thank you first. But if i use `e.preventDefault()` nothing happens. What is wrong with my code. But if I dont use it then update and inserting works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your click handler doesn't have `e.preventDefault()` in it. So after the AJAX call is sent, the form is also submitted normally. So even if you don't fill in `dataString`, the database will be updated from the form.

To make it only use AJAX, you should call `e.preventDefault()`. You also need to submit a value for the `submit` parameter, because the PHP code uses `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` to know if it should process the form parameters.

```
$("#id_submit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = $("#id_id").val();
    var fname = $("#id_fname").val(); 
    var lname = $("#id_lname").val();
    var age = $("#id_age").val();
    var dataString = "submit=submit&id="+id+ '&fname='+fname+'&lname='+lname+'&age='+age;
    //console.log(dataString);
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        data:dataString,
        url:'Registration.php',
        success:function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I have tried using `e.preventDefault()` but then inserting and updating is not working. I am new to javaScript, I found no error.

Comment: You didn't have `submit` in `dataString`, I've added it.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, values aren't getting passed. More over, the way you're trying to do ( ?id=...&fname=... etc) would be for passing it with $_GET.

You have to make something similar to :

```
$.ajax({
   type:'POST',
   data: { id : $("#id_id").val(), 
       fname : $("#id_fname").val(), 
       lname : $("#id_lname").val(),
       age : $("#id_age").val()
   },
 url:'Registration.php',
 success:function(data) {
     // code
 }
});
```

Comment: Thank you I did not know that. But if I use `e.preventDefault()` it does not work. Why???

Comment: You should put your PHP code in another file where you will only have it. e.preventDefaut() cancel the defaut action of your form (which is currently treated by your current page).

Answer (score 0):

`But when I removed that variable from my code data insert or update was still working. So how the passing of data working here.`

Answer

When you remove `var dataString` all the fields having `name` attribute are automatically submitted along with form

Comment: Is this process is done using ajax or it is the php code who is reponsible for that.

Comment: This is the action part from `<form action="" method="post">` who is doing it. empty action means it will be submited on the same page.

Comment: `method="post"` means form values will be hidden from querystring... <input type="submit">` means whenever this is clicked ... form will be posted


in short .... `submit` is the event for this